# Can we change the colour of a loaded SVG files using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible where we can change the colour of the SVG files?

For example, Load a tree SVG and change the colour of the leaves/foliage to green and the bark to brown.

We will need to create canvas/editor for this part.

I am quite newbies for the Javascript and I have searched across the internet to change for the SVG files. It seems like it is not possible to change the loaded SVG files.

Can people help to give some guidance on how to modify the SVG elements using Javascript by create canvas/editor?

Comment: search for svg color change, you'll find tons of examples.

Comment: can we change the colour for SVG image as well?

Comment: Can we load the .svg files and then read it using XMLRequest to get the data? Then, we just modify from there?

Answer (score 0):

In browsers that support SVG, you can manipulate SVG elements the same way you would with regular html elements. You can for example use an XMLHttpRequest to retrieve an SVG file, inject it in your document, and then apply styling.

There are a few things to pay attention to, for example:

- for namespaced SVG, make sure you use getElementsByTagNameNS. A library like jQuery might not be compatible with namespaces.
- class names are objects, you need to use their baseVal property to assign class names
- svg has its own css properties, for example use fill to assign a background color
- etc.

You'll find a lot of information on the Web, for example [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) or [this W3C page](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html).